# Replacing Letters in strings based of position in word

Tags: java, string, replace, split, substring

i'm writing a program to decipher a code using letter frequencies within the english language. For example, in the english language e is the most frequently used letter, it is used 13% of the time. In the cipher a is used roughly 13% of the time aswell so it is likely that a corresponds to e. However first letters of each words also have different frequencies. For example the letter 'T' is used 16.6% of the time as the first letter of a word, which corresponds to q in the cipher text.  Heres a link to more about it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency

The basic pseudo code im using is,

- Put cipher into a string and remove capitals
- Loop through the text counting the amount of time each letter appears
- Loop through the text count each first letter of a word
- Create a class to hold the letter value and the amount of times that letter appears
- Create an array of that class and have one for each letter
- Sort Arrays from highest to lowest
- Replace first letters with corresponding letters
- Replace other letters with their corresponding letters
- Should have a readable message

Ive gotten up to replacing letters stage. I know i can use replace to change letters, my problem however is how to only change the first letter of each word with their corresponding letter aswell as replacing the remaining letters, as both have different frequencys depending on whether it's the first letter or not.

any help would be greatly appeariated.

```
public class CodeCracker
{

    public CodeCracker() throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File cipher = new File("enciphered.txt");
        Scanner cipherInput = new Scanner(cipher);

        String cipherText = "";

        //add file to string
        while(cipherInput.hasNextLine()){
            cipherText += cipherInput.nextLine(); 
        }
        cipherText = cipherText.toLowerCase();
        //count total letters

        System.out.println("~~~Original Message~~~");
        System.out.println(cipherText);


        //****Count letter Occurences****
        List<LetterOccurence> allLettersPercentage = CountLetterPercentage(cipherText);
        List<LetterOccurence> firstLetterPercentage = CountFirstLetterPercentage(cipherText);
        for(int i = 0; i <firstLetterPercentage.size(); i++){
            //System.out.println(allLettersPercentage.get(i).GetLetter() + " - " + allLettersPercentage.get(i).GetOccurence());
           System.out.println(firstLetterPercentage.get(i).GetLetter() + " - " + firstLetterPercentage.get(i).GetOccurence());
        }
         System.out.println("~~~New Message~~~");
        System.out.println(CompareAllLetters(allLettersPercentage,cipherText));
    }

    //Counts occurence of each letter in text, makes a new object with the assigned letter and the percentage
    // of the letter occuring, then sorts them from highest to lowest and returns a list array
    public List<LetterOccurence> CountLetterPercentage(String text){
        double totalLetters = 0;                        //total letters in text
        totalLetters = text.length();                   
        String indexes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  //letters we are counting
        int[] count = new int [indexes.length()];       //array of ints for each letter   
        double[] letterPercentage = new double[indexes.length()];   //Percent of number of times the letter appears
        List<LetterOccurence> letterOccurences = new ArrayList<LetterOccurence>(indexes.length());  //list of LetterOccurence class
        //iterates through each letter and counts each occurence
        for(int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
            int index = indexes.indexOf(text.charAt(i));
            if (index < 0)
                continue;

            count[index]++;                             //count letter
        }
        //calculates letter percentages
        for( int i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
            if(count[i] < 1){
                continue;
            }
            //get percentage
            letterPercentage[i] = count[i] /totalLetters * 100;
            //create a class to store variables
            letterOccurences.add(new LetterOccurence(indexes.charAt(i),letterPercentage[i]));

        }
        //sort our array from highest to lowest
        Collections.sort(letterOccurences);  
        //return our array
        return letterOccurences;
    }
    public List<LetterOccurence> CountFirstLetterPercentage(String text){
        double totalLetters = 0;                        //total letters in text                  
        String indexes = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";  //letters we are counting
        int[] count = new int [indexes.length()];       //array of ints for each letter   
        double[] letterPercentage = new double[indexes.length()];   //Percent of number of times the letter appears
        List<LetterOccurence> letterOccurences = new ArrayList<LetterOccurence>(indexes.length());  //list of LetterOccurence class
        String firstLetters ="";
        String[] split = text.split(" ");
        for(String value : split){
            firstLetters += value.substring(0,1);
        }
        totalLetters = firstLetters.length();
        System.out.println(firstLetters);
        //iterates through each letter and counts each occurence
        for(int i = 0; i < firstLetters.length(); i++){
            int index = indexes.indexOf(firstLetters.charAt(i));
            if (index < 0)
                continue;

            count[index]++;                             //count letter
        }
        //calculates letter percentages
        for( int i = 0; i < count.length; i++){
            if(count[i] < 1){
                continue;
            }
            //get percentage
            letterPercentage[i] = count[i] /totalLetters * 100;
            //create a class to store variables
            letterOccurences.add(new LetterOccurence(indexes.charAt(i),letterPercentage[i]));

        }
        //sort our array from highest to lowest
        Collections.sort(letterOccurences);  
        //return our array
        return letterOccurences;
    }
    public String CompareAllLetters(List<LetterOccurence> codeLetters, String code){
        //Letter Frequency order
        char[] letterFrequency = {'e','t','a','o','i','n','s','h','r','d','l','c','u','m','w','f','g','y','p','b','v','k','j','x','q','z'};

        for(int i = 0;i < codeLetters.size(); i++){

            code = code.replace(codeLetters.get(i).GetLetter(),letterFrequency[i]); 
        }
        return code;

    }
}

public class LetterOccurence implements Comparable<LetterOccurence>{
    private char letter;
    private double occurence;
    public LetterOccurence(char letter, double occurence){
        this.letter = letter;
        this.occurence = occurence;
    }
    public double GetOccurence(){
        return occurence;
    }
    public char GetLetter(){
        return letter;
    }

    public int compareTo(LetterOccurence o){
        // return (occurence - o.occurence);
        return new Double(o.occurence).compareTo(new Double(this.occurence));
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldnt' space appear more often than e and a?

Comment: Yes space does appear more often than e and a, however the cipher text already includes spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Make `cipherText` a character array, then go through it and change a given character when you need to. Strings are immutable, so you cannot change a strings contents after you create it. Adding or subtracting from a string returns an *entirely* new string, instead of changing the value of the string. When you need to return a string, just:

```
return new String(cipherText);
```

using the `String(char[] array)` constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i was however having issues with the actual syntax, or the way i would go about changing the first letter of each word to its frequencies counterpart(Being the frequency for the first letters of words) and then the remaining letters based overall letter frequency.

Comment: Oh. How about having two `char` arrays, one with the cipher text, and one that is empty. As you go through the cipher array with the percentages (which you can store in some kind of `final HashMap<Double, Character>`) you can empty the cipher array, and fill in the second array that you initialized, containing the decoded string.